# Class 'Request' not found in blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, lumen

I'm having trouble with blade and the Request class from lumen. To change the class of a menu item I'm calling the 'is' method of the 'Request' class like this:

`{{ Request::is('thepage/*') ? 'class="active"' : '' }}`

Sadly everytime I open the page it results in

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Request' not found in /.../storage/framework/views/...

I really don't understand why that happens.

Comment: have you imported the class?

Comment: if I import it at the top of the blade file with '<?php use Illuminate\Http\Request; ?>' I'm getting 'Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::is() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context'. Which is logical, but how do I get the context in a view?

Comment: you are using that on view?

Comment: well actually the `Request` class extends `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request`

Comment: Ok, but the Symfony Request class doesn't have the 'is' method and anyway it would be same result if I import the Symfony class instead of the Illuminate one.

Comment: well i normaly don't use the `{{Request::anything}}` in the blade. however i use it on the controller, and then i call it on the view like `{{anything('what_you_want_to_check')}}`.

Comment: i never used the `::is()` method though so why don't you use it inside an if contition without the curly braces?

Comment: Using it inisde an if condition is exactly the same thing (tried it, same result).

Comment: Oh my, I'm not that familiar with Lumen yet and forgot to activate facades. Now it works.

Answer (score 4):

Add this line of code to withFacades() function on /vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php file

```
class_alias('Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request', 'Request');
```

Comment: Nice answer... that's exactly what you do

Answer (score 0):

```
@if(\Request::is(thepage/*)

    /*do something*/

@endif
```

try this, it worked for me

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Lumen yet and forgot to activate facades. Now it works.

Comment: @lukasgeiter it's an if condition, and as far as it works where's the problem

Comment: yea i tried with the backslash and it worked first go.. now i'm seeing that it works with no backslash also